# Read text content from XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xelement

In .NET, how do I read the text content from an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)?

For example, from the XElement

```
XElement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>")
```

I would like the string 'Alice & Bob'

---

I tried `element.Value` but that returns 'Alice & Bobcat' :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's badly formed XML, which is why you're having a problem.  Tags should contain either a value or other tags, not both.

Comment: `<p>Perfectly normal for that popular XML language called <b>HTML</b></p>`

Comment: Actually, HTML isn't XML and vice versa.  They're related, certainly, but only XHTML is both.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML.  If you're going to be parsing HTML, you should use a HTML parser.  If you're parsing XML, I still think this is badly formed.

Comment: I'm not sure if the standard changed between now and then, but that is well formed XML by the current standard.  The `tag` node has two child nodes, one text node and one element node.  The issue does get more complicated with DTDs or schemas, in which case it may not be possible to exactly specify such a format.

Comment: @Bobson: this is valid xml, so you can't state "badly formed xml" only because you think that this is bad practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 XElement t = XElement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>");
 string s = (t.FirstNode as XText).Value;
```

Answer (score 7):

Just because I recently had a similar requirement, I'm offering up:

```
var x = XElement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>")
var text = string.Concat(x.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value));
```

Will not capture text content of child nodes, but will concatenate all untagged text nodes in the current element.

Comment: This is the most flexible\generic and therefore useful answer.

Comment: This but without the concat is great.  The concat will just merge strings and make the result ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Using `element.FirstNode` you can get the raw content that you have inside the element, "Alice & Bob", so you only need to "unescape" the ampersand and you will get the result that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code It might help you..

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parent = XElement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>");
            var nodes = from x in parent.Nodes()
                            where x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                            select (XText)x;

            foreach (var val in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement t= XElement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>");
string s = t.FirstNode.ToString();
```

Comment: try using this string s = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string.Format(t.FirstNode.ToString()))); Make sure the System.Web Dll is being referenced.

Comment: you can also use this as well  string s = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode((string.Format(t.FirstNode.ToString())));

Comment: but this also works. The escaped special chars are no reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement t= Xelement.Parse("<tag>Alice &amp; Bob<other>cat</other></tag>");
string s = t.toString();
```